# Error running tests in gradle using cucumber tags

Tags: gradle, cucumber, junit5, serenity-bdd

Currently when I run a test using cucumber and junit tags I get an error when I run the command:

```
gradle test -DCucumber.options="--tags @LOGIN" 
gradle test -DCucumber.filter.tags="@LOGIN"
```

The error I get is this:
using `gradle test -DCucumber.options="--tags @LOGIN"` 
[case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwvp8.png)

using `gradle test -DCucumber.filter.tags="@LOGIN"`
[case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7LZi.png)

Here is the Gradle configuration I am currently using.

```
plugins{
    id "java"
    id "eclipse"
    id "idea"
    id "net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin" version "4.0.15"
}

group "org.example"
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories { mavenCentral() }

sourceCompatibility = 16
targetCompatibility = 16

ext {
    serenity_version = "4.0.15"
    junit_platform_launcher_version =" 1.10.0"
    cucumber_junit_platform_engine_version = "7.14.0"
    junit_platform_suite_version = "1.10.0"
    junit_jupiter_engine_version = "5.9.3"
    junit_vintage_engine_version = "5.9.3"
    logback_classic_version = "1.2.10"
    assertj_core_version = "3.23.1"
    slf4j_version = "2.0.5"
}
dependencies {
    implementation(
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-ensure:${serenity_version}",
            "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:${cucumber_junit_platform_engine_version}",
            "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4j_version}",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logback_classic_version}",
            "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertj_core_version}"
    )

    testCompileOnly(
            "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite:${junit_platform_suite_version}",
            "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junit_jupiter_engine_version}",
            "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:${junit_vintage_engine_version}",
            "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:${junit_platform_launcher_version}"
    )
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "cucumber.filter.tags", System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.tags")
    testLogging { showStandardStreams = true }
    finalizedBy(aggregate)
}

serenity { reports = ["single-page-html"] }

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
test.finalizedBy aggregate
```

The version of gradle and java that we use are:

[verions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWiX4.png)

I have searched many forums but cannot find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Is `Cucumber` in `-DCucumber..` case sensitive?  We always do a lower case `c`.

Comment: @User51 I have tried and the same error still occurs: ```gradle test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@LOGIN"```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why PowerShell Splits Arguments At Dots In Some Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979247/why-powershell-splits-arguments-at-dots-in-some-cases)

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Thanks, I was able to solve the errors I had